# Bind context when event binding on $(document)

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, jquery-events

The situation is like this:
I have a div which we can get using `$('#container')` and a child div of this div is `('#tracker')`.
On tracker I bind a event as:

```
$(document).on('mousemove', '#tracker', function(e) {
    console.log(e.clientX);
}
```

However, I wish to bind it in context of the container, i.e. I wish functionality same as:

```
$('#tracker', '#container').onmousemove = function() { ... }
```

but applied to the document. Or suggestions stating otherwise

**[EDIT]**
Sorry for vague original question.

If I try to cache, then I can do `var v = $('#tracker', '#container')` and then I can do `v.onmousemove = function () { ... }`

How does this work for:

```
$(document).on('mousemove', <cached in var>, function(e) {
    console.log(e.clientX);
}
```

Comment: You should already have that same functionality, since ID values are unique. Context should make no difference to them.

Comment: @JamesAllardice The only time it really makes sense is when you're sharing scripts between pages, both have a single `#tracker` element each but only one of them is inside a `#container` element (and you only want the functionality on that page).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just extend the selector passed to `.on()` to only find `#tracker` elements that are inside a `#container` element:

```
$(document).on('mousemove', '#container #tracker', function(e) {
    console.log(e.clientX);
});
```

If you want to cache the object in another variable there are a few ways you could do that. The first is the same as before, but you won't be using it when you call `.on()`:

```
var v = $('#tracker', '#container');

$(document).on('mousemove', '#container #tracker', function(e) {
    // use v here
});

// you can also use v here
```

Or, if you only ever need it *inside* of the event handler function, you could do it this way:

```
$(document).on('mousemove', '#container #tracker', function(e) {
    var v = $(this);
    // use v here
});
```

Comment: Ah sorry, just took a couple of coffees after seeing responses. I'll update the question

Comment: What I wished to ask for was: I can cache `var v = $('#tracker', '#container')` and then I can do `v.onmousemove = function() { ... }`. How can I do the same in document counterpart

Comment: @gashu Which part do you want cached? Though I can't see why you'd need to do so. If you need to refer to the `#tracker` element inside the function you can just use `this` (for the actual DOM node) or `$(this)` (for a jQuery object containing it). You could cache that inside the function: `var v = $(this);`.

Comment: @gashu Oh, wait, need to read more carefully. Your second snippet isn't correct; it sets a property on the jQuery object, but won't bind any event handlers.

Comment: @gashu Edited my answer to (hopefully) address what it is you want.

Comment: Being a bit too annoying but I know how to use v as shown in updated answers, what I was not able to understand is how does the binding `$(document).on('mousemove', '#container #tracker', function(e) {` works? i.e. performance wise. However, I am accepting your answer as correct as it clearly explains my original question and google for how such bindings work. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I may be getting this wrong, because it seems a little obvious, but is this what you're wanting?

```
$(document).on('mousemove', '#container #tracker', function(e) {

}
```

Comment: Ah sorry, just took a couple of coffees after seeing responses. I'll update the question – gashu 1 min ago edit 
What I wished to ask for was: I can cache var v = $('#tracker', '#container') and then I can do v.onmousemove = function() { ... }. How can I do the same in document counterpart